# OpenERP POS Epson Printer

Tags: printing, odoo, epson, receipt

I have installed an Epson TM-T20 on my ubuntu 13.10 as the receipt printer. Unfortunately, it's printing in A4 size with a picture of the receipt.  Can anyone help me to modify the system to print on the 80mm receipt paper.

Also, when I press print on OpenERP POS webclient on the iPad after a transaction it doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.